# Delphi 7 RLINK32 Error reading dfm file - failed read

Tags: delphi, dfm

I just run into a problem that came out of nowhere...
A DFM file gets read just fine from Delphi when project is built, but when I build it from command line (dcc32) I get error `Error: RLINK32: Error reading file "update.dfm" Failed read`

What is more stranger another project containing same file builds with no error from both Delphi and dcc.

Does anyone have a clue of what could cause something like this?

I tried to build from another location, still same.

Operating system is Windows Server 2008. Permissions seems correct.

Comment: Is it included in the project or just found via search path?

Comment: I would suggest you to check elevations more in depth

Comment: It is included in project, this one and others. Only this one has a problem and only on this machine compiled via dcc.

Comment: Maybe I should ask this - why would dcc throw "RLINK - Failed read" error? I could then check all possible causes and maybe find the one that caused this...

Comment: Can you check whether dcc32 uses the correct search path?

Comment: dcc32 is using correct search path, globally defined in dcc32.cfg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SysInternals [**Process Monitor**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx), and watch when it goes looking for `update.dfm`.

You'll probably see DCC32 frantically searching everywhere for `update.dfm` (except the place where it is). Or maybe it will find it, but `OpenFile` fails with an error.

Either way: you'll find out what exactly is going on.

Comment: Well thank you very much for this tip! The problem resolved itself out of nowhere...but I believe next time I will catch it with this...

Comment: Will definately try this.  Get RLINK erors all the time - Delphi 6.  Perhaps this will guide me to the answer

Answer (score 0):

To try and narrow the cause of the problem down, open the dfm with a text editor, and gradually remove properties and save until the build works.  That would at least indicate if it's a problem with a particular component in the dfm.

Answer (score 0):

The main thing that is different with a dcc32 is the library path in the environment options. When you build from the IDE this is used. When you run dcc32 you need to specify this.

You can do this by setting the library path for the -I and -U options on dcc32, or you can use a dcc32.cfg file to hold all your configuration for the build.

RLINK32 can signify duplicate resource so consider renaming one of the forms so as to avoid the clash. Having said that hopefully the library path should resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I found this after having the same problem which seemed to happen randomly from time to time if I changed a bit of code of added a copied a component, this time the only difference I made was changing an `=` to `<>` but changing it back worked fine except now I've changed something else it's happening again - hence the reason how I found this.  Being quite a newb I didn't really understand some of the other bits mentioned here but I just found by building the project first before pressing <kbd>F9</kbd> seemed to work..  just for now at least.

Hope this helps someone! :)

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this happen when you remove a value from an enum type and that value was being used in the dfm. The next time you opened the dfm the IDE would put garbage text in where the value was. Delphi 2010 if that helps.

I would just open the dfm in a text editor and remove the corrupt text.